# Как получить данные с View для AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, dialogfragment, android-dialog

У меня проблема.

Данные с `EditText` пустые, а с `Spinner` получаю первое значение. Пробовал разные комбинации.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setView(R.layout.add_recipe)
                .setPositiveButton("Додати", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        AppCompatSpinner spinner;
                        EditText title;
                        EditText description;
                        View view;

                        view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.add_recipe, null);
                        spinner = (AppCompatSpinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

                        title = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_title);

                        description = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_description);
                        Recipe recipe = new Recipe();
                        String ms = title.getText().toString().trim();
                        Log.i("message", "you add" + ms);
                        recipe.setName(title.getText().toString());
                        recipe.setDescription(description.getText().toString());
                        recipe.setTable(Tables.values()[spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()].getTableName());
                        RecipeLab.getInstance(getActivity()).addRecipe(recipe);
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                })

                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
```

Кто встречался с такой проблемой помогите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы в слушателе загружаете новый экземпляр разметки диалога вместо обращения к разметке отображаемого диалога. Попробуйте скастовать агрумент метода к диалогу и взять его разметку так:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setView(R.layout.add_recipe)
            .setPositiveButton("Додати", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    AppCompatSpinner spinner;
                    EditText title;
                    EditText description;
                    Dialog view;

                    view = ((Dialog)dialog);
                    ...
                }
            })

            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
```

Comment: не работает java.lang.ClassCastException.Кстати все это в DialogFragnent

Comment: В ошибке у васнаписано какой класс получилмя. Попробуйте его. Наверно это AlertDialog

Comment: это работает, спасибо за помощь. На счет Exception это моя вина вместо Dialog view, я написал View view